# Swift TableView in a UIView not displaying data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a page which should have a map on the top and 5 row tableview at the bottom. So i created UIViewController put my Map View then put TableView. I created myViewController.swift and myTableViewCell.swift

But when i try on simulator no data showing on tableview. Only empty cells.I received no error

Here is my code. Thank you

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class myViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var labels = ["some arrays"]

    var images = ["some image names in an array"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySegue", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell

        cell.myCellLabel.text = labels[indexPath.row]
        cell.myCellImage.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add this
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: I was trying really hard to fix the issue but the solution is that easy?:) Thank you very much

Comment: what this two lines really do? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jorgesaraiva, The first line connect the delegate method to your delegate methods and the same for the 2nd line for datasource methods. Your TableView need these methods to start working and interacting. You need to tell to your TableView in which Class are its delegate & datasource methods. In our case it's the controller class thats why we write "self"

Answer (score 7):

You should do one out of two way :

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

in the viewDidLoad() of your viewController 
OR
 - select the tableView and dragging by pressing control to viewController, first select the datasource and again doing so select the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Assign delegate and datasource of UITableView/ UICollectionView through storyboard to reduce code as follows:

Right click on your UITableView, then click on round circle for Delegate/ Datasource and move on to the viewcontroller. For clarity, see the image below.

[image: Click here to view screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataSource of the tableview.

tableview.dataSource = self
tableview.delegate = self

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add this
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}